# Remove SNPs with wrong alleles

Tags: python, bash, unix, extract, rows

I have two files that look like this:

1. The reference panel (**ReferencePanel.csv**)

   > ```
   > "id","position","allele0","allele1","allele1_frequency"
   > "seq-rs1010355",55102179,"T","C",0.098
   > "seq-rs272408",55103603,"C","T",0.787
   > "seq-rs11669899",55104559,"A","T",0.029
   > "imm_19_59798585",55106773,"A","G",0.499
   > ```
2. A BIM file (**myfile.bim**)

   > ```
   > 19    19:55102179    0    55102179    C    T
   > 19    19:55103603    0    55103603    C    T
   > 19    19:55104559    0    55104559    G    C
   > 19    19:55106773    0    55106773    A    T
   > ```

I would like to **delete** in the BIM file all the rows where the two alleles are different from the reference panel. In other words, I would like to keep only the rows that have exactly the same alleles as the reference panel - the order does not matter.

**EXAMPLE**:

Reference allele:

> ```
> "seq-rs1010355",55102179,"T","C",0.098
> "seq-rs272408",55103603,"C","T",0.787
> "seq-rs11669899",55104559,"A","T",0.029
> "imm_19_59798585",55106773,"A","G",0.499
> ```

BIM file (myfile.bim)

> ```
> 19    19:55102179 0   55102179    C   T
> 19    19:55103603 0   55103603    C   T
> 19    19:55104559 0   55104559    G   C
> 19    19:55106773 0   55106773    A   T
> ```

Keep only the following rows:

> ```
> 19    19:55102179 0   55102179    C   T
> 19    19:55103603 0   55103603    C   T
> ```

I managed to extract all the positions from the reference panel using these lines:

```
#Create an empty list 
positions=[]

#Populate list with positions 
for line in open("ReferencePanel.csv"):
    columns = line.split(",")
    positions.append(columns[1])
#Remove first element which corresponds to the header
positions.pop(0)
```

But I am stuck here. I hope someone can help me. 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you're not against using `awk`, you can use the following command:

```
awk -F'[",]*' 'NR==FNR && $4 && $5 {ref[$4][$5]=1} NR>FNR {FS=" *"} NR>FNR && ref[$6][$7]' reference.csv myfile.bim
```

which is resulting in:

```
19    19:55102179    0    55102179    C    T
19    19:55103603    0    55103603    C    T
19    19:55106773    0    55106773    A    T
```

Note the last line matches the 4th line of the reference file (with A, T)

*Explanation:*

`-F'[",]*'` is matching the CSV delimiter for parsing the reference file

`NR==FNR && $4 && $5 {ref[$4][$5]=1}` is getting all C,T,G,A from the reference file

`NR>FNR {FS=" *"}` is changing the `awk` field separator to spaces to parse the second file

`NR>FNR && ref[$6][$7]` is printing line of the second file if the 6th and 7th column is matching what was stored in the array

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer oliv. I really appreciate! However I get a syntax error using this command. I think there is something wrong/missing between [$4][$5], and the same between [$6][$7]. Moreover, I don't understand why you use columns 4 and 5 for the reference file (I would use 3 and 4), and 6 and 7 for the second file (I would use columns 5 and 6).

Comment: I use GNU Awk 4.1.3 and that script works fine, what is your version? 
The script uses index 4 and 5 for extracting data out of the reference file because the delimiter `[",]*` also matches the first `"` at the beginning of line and so the awk variable `$1` is empty.

Comment: I am connecting to Linux from Mac OS X by using Terminal, and I am using version 2.6.32-358.23.2.el6.x86_64 (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313).

Comment: I get 2 awk syntax errors: one indicates the second opening square bracket (the one before '$5'); and the other points to the 4th opening square bracket (the one before '$7').

Comment: weird... try removing the middle square bracket to have `ref[$4$5]` and `ref[$6$7]`. If this doesn't work, try `gawk` (instead of `awk`). At last please provide the output of `awk --version` and the output of the error.